# Facebook comment plugin comments disapear after refresh

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, plugins, comments

I tried adding the comment plugin for facebook to my website. Its a neocities domain so i dont know if that has anything to do with it. I made a new app then went here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/
and got my code and put it where it should be put. The box works but as soon as i refresh the page the comment disapears.
Here the page: http://thepokeprognostication.neocities.org/forum.welcome.html

Comment: did you go to the dashboard and change it from development mode to public?

Comment: yes I did. It still disappears.